# Unable to capture screenshot. Prevented by security policy. Galaxy S6. Android 6.0

Tags: android, screen, screenshot, galaxy

Does someone know how to turn off this screen?

[image]

Also phone has a message (Toast) when trying to make a screenshot:

> Unable to capture screenshot. Prevented by security policy

.

One of recommendations was to update policy, but didn't help: `Menu --> Settings --> Lockscreen & Security --> Other Security Settings --> Security Policy Updates`

[Screen photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ouiud.jpg)

Comment: Flagged for closing as blatantly off-topic. This question has nothing to do with *programming*.

Comment: Then why wasn't the question migrated to a more appropriate exchange website?

Comment: If this happens on a specific application its because the app is coded the way. Basically using `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Phone Settings --> Developer Options --> Simulate Secondary Displays` and turn it to `None`.
If you don't see `Developer Options` in the `settings menu` (it should be at the bottom, go `Settings ==> About phone` and tap on the `Build number` a lot of times)

Comment: Avoid trying to answer off-topic questions here. Flag them instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had that message "security policy prevents use of camera" after phone update and all i found out from internet was that i must reset my phone.. so i just stopped using camera.

I also had an app something like "camera blocker" manually installed and used before, a paid one. So one day i just thought that maybe that camera blocker app does something..

So I've tried to uninstall it. But i was not allowed to uninstall that program. Seen a mini button that this app has an admin control.. So entered that page with admin controlled apps and turned that admin control off. Then uninstalled that camera blocker app from the camera blocker app settings.

**And suddenly my camera was available!**

Been without camera for weeks and i needed this badly several times. But now finally this problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0):

You must have either `disabled`, `froze` or `uninstalled` **FaceProvider** in `settings>applications>all`
This will only happen if it's `frozen`, either `uninstall` it, or `enable` it.

Comment: I know this, but was not my case. Just a stupid mistake. Probably was turned on when it was in a pocket. thank you for your answer

Comment: Avoid trying to answer off-topic questions here. Flag them instead. Thanks.